# Reset Arduino firmware

Tags: arduino, flip, firmware, dfu

I used Flip to transform my Arduino into a MIDI controller. Now I want it to be back to normal. I took the firmware from the IDE folder (Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3), but when I am using Flip to put the old firmware back, I get the error *"Address is out of range"*. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: is your Uno R3? older revision had atmega8u2. https://startingelectronics.org/articles/arduino/uno-r3-r2-differences/

Comment: Yes, it's a R3.

Comment: Related: *[Updating ATmega16U2](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54937)*